# SKLearn: SelectKBest Ignores Seemingly Relevant Features

Tags: machine-learning, python, feature-selection, scikit-learn

I'm trying to predict engagement time for an article from the text of the article itself.  I'm extracting a bunch of features such as number of words in article, number of characters in article, number of paragraphs in article, etc.

Then I do TFIDF to get a ton more features.

Finally, I do this:

```
selector = SelectKBest(k=1000)
X = pd.DataFrame(selector.fit_transform(X, y))
```

Effectively, I want to get the top 1,000 most relevant features.  However, when I inspect it with:

```
X.head()
```

It looks like all TFIDF features; that is, it's implying that length of article in words or characters isn't a top 1,000 feature.

This seems very wrong.

Could someone tell me what I'm doing incorrectly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to predict engagement time (=regression) for an article.

Now you want to use the function "selectKBest()". As we see in the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.SelectKBest.html#sklearn.feature_selection.SelectKBest), the function `SelectKBest(score_func=<function f_classif>, k=10)` requires two input parameters.

Since you only specified one input parameter, the other is per definition set to default as it is also stated in the documentation:

> Default is f_classif (see below “See also”). The default function
>   only works with classification tasks.

There we have the issue. The equivalent to the default score function in case of regression is called "f_regression".